# On toggle mat-slide-toggle method call is not working in Angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular8

I am trying to call each tree graph view of echarts on a toggle button click, for that for one toggle click i have called one method and for the reverse of this i am calling the other method to show different graph view. But unfortunately the toggle is working but the function call is not working. See my below code:

On toggle each method is going to display different graph view. I need to show 2 graph views based on selection.

My 2 methods are below:

```
showGraph: boolean = false;
    formatJsonObject() {
        let formattedObj = { name: "API", children: [] };
        let childrenObj = this.resourceDefinitionList.map((x) => {
            let obj = {} as any;
            obj.name = x.resourceName;
            obj.children = x.endpoints.map(y => { return { name: y.description } });
            return obj;
        });
        formattedObj.children = childrenObj;
        this.showGraph = true;
        this.graph1Options = {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            tooltip: {
                trigger: 'item',
                triggerOn: 'mousemove'
            },
            toolbox: {
                feature: {
                    saveAsImage: {
                        title: 'Save'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    type: 'tree',
                    data: [formattedObj],
                    top: '18%',
                    bottom: '18%',
                    layout: 'radial',
                    symbol: 'emptyCircle',
                    symbolSize: 7,
                    initialTreeDepth: 1,
                    roam: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    focusNodeAdjacency: true,
                    expandAndCollapse: true,
                    animationDuration: 450,
                    animationDurationUpdate: 550
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    formatJsonObjectLeve2() {
        let formattedObj = { name: "API", children: [] };
        let childrenObj = this.resourceDefinitionList.map((x) => {
            let obj = {} as any;
            obj.name = x.resourceName;
            obj.children = x.endpoints.map(y => { return { name: y.description } });
            return obj;
        });
        formattedObj.children = childrenObj;
        this.showGraph = true;
        this.graph1Options = {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            tooltip: {
                trigger: 'item',
                triggerOn: 'mousemove'
            },
            toolbox: {
                feature: {
                    saveAsImage: {
                        title: 'Save'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    type: 'tree',
                    data: [formattedObj],
                    top: '18%',
                    bottom: '18%',
                    layout: 'radial',
                    symbol: 'emptyCircle',
                    symbolSize: 7,
                    initialTreeDepth: 3,
                    roam: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    focusNodeAdjacency: true,
                    expandAndCollapse: true,
                    animationDuration: 450,
                    animationDurationUpdate: 550
                }
            ]
        };
    }
```

Toggle method:

```
public viewNameTree = false;
toggleTreeView() {
        this.viewNameTree = !this.viewNameTree;
        if (this.viewNameTree == true) {
            this.formatJsonObject();
        } else {
            this.formatJsonObjectLeve2();
        }
        console.log(this.viewNameTree)
    }
```

Template code:

```
<mat-slide-toggle (click)="toggleTreeView()" color="primary">{{viewNameTree}}</mat-slide-toggle>
```